# Here we go vs here we are

Tags: sentence, sentence-patterns

Could someone explain me the difference between the following

> here we are

And

> here we go

Many thanks,
Duilio

Comment: "Here we go" is said at the beginning of a trip (literal or figurative).  "Here we are" is said at the end.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you refer to the use of these phrases as some sort of interjection that focusses attention on present circumstance. For example, a family arrives at the beach after a journey: "Well, children, here we are!" marks the conclusion of the preceding train of events. When the family goes on the roller coaster and is at the top of the slope ready to start: "Well, children, here we go!" marks the beginning of something that is now inevitable.

Comment: Yes, Anton's answer is more succinct than mine. I shall probably edit mine to focus on other possible usages.

Comment: Nice answer, Anton.  I had a mental picture of waiting for food in a restaurant, and you're right...  Upon the arrival of the food, "Here we are," would refer to the end of 'waiting', and "Here we go," would refer to the start of the meal.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a scenario in which (in colloquial U.S. English, anyway) the two phrases may be used interchangeably: You stop by a coworker's office and ask to see a proposal that the person worked on six months earlier. The person says "Sure, it's in my 'Done' file. Let me get it for you." The person rummages around for a minute or so, and then pulls out the requested document, saying

> Here we are.

or

> Here we go.

Both wordings are common, colloquially correct, and equivalent in meaning.

In other instances—as other answerers have suggested—"here we are" and "here we go" retain literal meanings that emphasize position or state (in the case of "here we are") or the commencement of action or movement (in the case of "here we go").

Answer (score 0):

**"Here we are"** indicates location.

**"Here we go"** indicates imminent motion.

> **Note**
>
> There are exceptions - for instance in a restaurant when delivering
>   food.

**Examples of basic meaning**

**1.** Some children are hiding indoors from their parents as a game.

Mother: Where are the children?

Father: I don't know.

They search for the children for a few minutes.

Mother: I give up, I can't find them anywhere.

Children (*jumping out from behind the settee*): Here we are!

Father: Oh there you are!

Mother: We couldn't find you anywhere.

---

**2.** Jane and John are at an amusement park. They are on the big dipper.

Jane: When is the ride going to start?

John: It is taking a long time.

Jane: I think we have to wait for all the seats to be full.

John: That could take a long time.

*The big dipper starts to move.*

Jane: Here we go!

John: At last!

---

**Note**

There may be slight variations in meaning. What country are you learning English in? What part of the country? Where are you when this is being said? What is happening?